# limits and rules of derivation

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm stuck with the application of the rules of derivation.
I've got this exercise:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x^2}- 2 \cos x +1}{x^2\log(1+3x^2)}.$$
After doing the calculations I see that this limit $=0/0.$
So I must to use Hopital theorem $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$
So I'm going to calculate derivative of the numerator and it's $$=-2xe^{-x^2}+2\sin x$$
But I've got the problem calculate the derivative of the denominator $${x^2\log(1+3x^2)}.$$
I had to use the chain rule $$D[f(g(x))]=f'(g(x)g'(x).$$ My $f(x)$ is $2x$ so $f'(x)=0.$ My $$g(x)={\log(1+3x^2)}$$ and I can't do the correct derivation of this last because I use the formula $$f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=0×6x+1×3x^2=3x^2.$$ Now I'm using it again with $$(\log x)'×3x^2=1/x×3x^2+\log6x=3x/\log 6x=1/\log 2$$
So now I'm using Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2xe^{-x^2}+2\sin x}{1/\log 2}=0/0.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the base of log ?

Comment: is not indicated, it should be the natural logarithm

Comment: Then change it to $\ln$ because it can create misunderstanding

Comment: @HarshitGupta done :)

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the denominator is

$$2xlog(1+3x^2)+x^2\cdot\frac{6x}{1+3x^2}$$

(First you apply the derivative of the product between $x^2$ and $log(1+3x^2)$ then for the derivative of $log(1+3x^2)$ you use the chain rule)

It's still in the form $\frac{0}{0}$ but this does not mean you are doing something wrong

Comment: I calculate the right limit and the left limit. And they're +∞ and - ∞, so this limit it doesn't exist

Comment: No, the limit is $\frac{5}{36}$ but using the l'Hospital's ruse is not the best way to achieve this result. Do you know what are asymptotic equivalences or better Taylor's expansions of a function?

Comment: I'm just studying it. It's must be something like 2xlog(1+3x)~3x, x^2~0. But I may use it just if the limit =1 and in this case my limit it's 0/0

Comment: wait, if $x\rightarrow0$ then $log(1+3x^2) \sim 3x^2$ so the whole denominator is asymptotic to $x^2\cdot 3x^2$. (I am talking about the starting limit, not after the derivation).

Comment: nope, I don't know that. I may say also that at the numerator $e^x-1~x and cos x-1~(1/)x, but I don't know to work with them

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac {e^{-x^2}\,-\,2Cos\,x \,+1\,}{x^2\,log(1\,+3x^2)}) $ $\\$

$ \lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{(1\,-x^2/1!\,+x^4/2! +......)+1-2(1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!.....)}{x^2(3x^2-9x^4/2+......)} $ $\\$
$=\frac{5}{36}$

Comment: What theorem or rule did you use to develop those calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Here Ur mistake is that derivative of 2x is 2 not 0 and derivative of g(x) is $\frac {6x}{1+3x^2}$

Comment: oh yes, because of the rule D[k*f(x)]=k*f'(x), k=2 and f(x)=x so it's will be 2*1=2

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Is not it better to write down
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x^2}- 2 \cos x +1}{x^2\ln(1+3x^2)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-u}- 2 \cos \sqrt u +1}{u\ln(1+3u)}$$and apply the L^Hopital's rule twice?

Answer (score 0):

OK, to find the derivative of the denominator, proceed as follows:

$$[x^2\log (1+3x^2)]'=(x^2)'\log (1+3x^2)+x^2[\log (1+3x^2)]'=2x\log (1+3x^2) + x^2\frac{1}{1+3x^2}(1+3x^2)'=2x\log (1+3x^2) + \frac{x^2}{1+3x^2}\times 6x=2x\log (1+3x^2) + \frac{6x^3}{1+3x^2}.$$